# Can't connect to local socket, connection refused

Tags: php, linux, sockets, connection

I've been at this for a few days now and just can't crack the problem. I've also put it up on the Ubuntu forum and heard nothing.  Basically, I have a local socket in /tmp/mysockets which I create successfully in a php script--

```
if (($sock = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM,0)) === false) 
{
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
        exit();
}
```

but to which I cannot connect, via

```
if (socket_connect($sock, $sock_str) === false) 
{
        echo "socket_connect() on " . $sock_str . " failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_$
        socket_close($sock);
        exit();
}
```

This gives me

> Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [111]: Connection refused
>   in /var/www/myscript.php on line 66 socket_connect() on
>   /tmp/mysockets/sock failed: reason: Connection refused

Now, I thought this might be a permissions issue, but I've chmod 777'ed the /tmp, mysockets, and sock, and it doesn't matter. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you call `socket_listen()` ?

Comment: @stewe The script already fails on socket_bind(), see below

Comment: What, if anything, is listening to the socket? You can't connect to a socket that nobody's listening for connections on.

Comment: @duskwuff A process that is launched earlier in the script is listening to it.  Actually in other virtually identical scripts which do work I don't have socket_bind(); I just put that in here at the suggestion of the commentators.

Comment: Are you sure that process has started listening by the time you try to connect? You may be racing ahead of it.

Comment: @duskwuff Great idea but even adding a usleep(5000000) didn't change things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that the process that was supposed to be listening for this socket crashed--I'm doing this remotely (and I'm just getting used to remote compiling/debugging) so I didn't see this at first.  Sorry guys I described the problem incorrectly.  @duskwuff you had the right idea.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `socket_bind()` and `socket_listen()` after `socket_create()`.

Comment: Thanks I tried socketbind($sock, '127.0.0.1') and got 'could not bind, permission denied' so this is progress, but I like I said everything is 777.  What does it mean?

Comment: If you're trying to bind to a low-numbered port, you'll need to be root.

Comment: @Michael get_current_user() returns 'root'.

Comment: What port number are you trying to use?

Comment: It's a UNIX domain socket -- it's identified by a path, not an IP/port pair.