# 'Connection refused' in tcp socket?

Tags: php, sockets, development-environment

So, we are coding a web chat client for our current IM, and i have one issue, socket_connect will NOT connect, and throws the "error Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [111]: Connection refused in /home/shadowri/public_html/zapf/personal.php on line 29" how would i get it to connect exactly, as it has to connect to the socket and send a handshake after that, then how would i get it to read every time they receive an message? i know its listening on that tcp socket, as our pc client uses it and simply connects directly then sends the handshake? am i missing something"

Comment: You simple have a firewall issue ... My Guess

Comment: This seems a duplicate of at least one other question [Similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211827/cant-connect-to-local-socket-connection-refused)  Review that question to make sure it is not your issue.  Also if it is not your question you probably need to add some code so we can see exactly what is breaking

Comment: and how exactly would i make it receive each IM correctly? just repeatedly execute read?

Comment: google for stuff like php socket server to see code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Either there is a firewall in the way or there is nothing listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.